# How to determine whether attachTo() is completed in LoopbackJS?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Here is example:

```
myModel.attachTo(app.datasources.mysqlDB, function (err){
        console.log(err);
});
```

This way I can handle only error but not complete of function. How to identify that model is attached to datasource ?

Comment: if(!err){ //function is completed}

Comment: Isn't helpful. Callback function doesn't execute if no error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look how attach method works at node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js you will see that your model emits event "dataSourceAttached" when it connects to datasource. You can listen for this event and do your staff accordingly. Please note that this event will not be emitted if your model is already attached to the datasource that you are trying to attachTo.

```
myModel.on('dataSourceAttached', function (modelClass) {
      console.log('dataSourceAttached');
//do something
    });
....
myModel.attachTo(app.datasources.mysqlDB);
```